# Dirac Notation Property

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, wavefunction, observables

Suppose we had the following:

$$\langle \psi|\hat A|\psi\rangle$$

but $\psi$ can be broken into factors $\psi_1 \psi_2$ so

$$\langle \psi_1 \psi_2|\hat A|\psi_1 \psi_2\rangle$$

is there some way this can be split up?

Like perhaps?

$$=\langle \psi_1|\hat A|\psi_1\rangle \langle \psi_2|\hat A|\psi_2\rangle$$

I couldn't find any properties like this online or in my textbooks

Comment: That's because there is no such property. Think about $\hat{A}$ being the momentum operator (which is in essence a derivative) and you'll see that it doesn't satisfy this property.

Comment: what is the meaning of $|\psi_1\psi_2\rangle$? Is it a tensor product?

Comment: @user2723984 The question spawned from a Hydrogen atom problem I didn't understand. The idea was $|\psi \rangle = |\psi_1 \psi_2 \rangle = R_{n,l}(r)Y_{l,m}(\theta ,\phi)$. Please correct me if this approach makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good example of misuse of Dirac's *bra* and *ket* notation. Kets are not intended to be a fancy notation for  wavefunctions. They should represent states in a more abstract way than using position dependent wavefunctions. According to your clarification comment, you intend $|\psi\rangle$ as a shortened notation for $_{nl}(r)Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi)$. In a consistent Dirac notation it should be
$$
\langle {\bf r}|\psi\rangle = _{nl}(r)Y_{lm}(\theta, \phi).
$$
Anyway, a part problems of notation, your question can be recast in the simpler formalism of position wavefunctions and operators acting on these functions. Let me indicate as $(f,{\bf A}f)$ the scalar product of a function $f$ by the function ${\bf A}f$ resulting from applying an operator  ${\bf A}$ to wavefunction $f$.
Then, it becomes the question whether, assuming that the $F$ Is factorized as $f(r,\theta,\phi)=R(r)Y(\theta,\phi)$, there is a simpler structure for $(f,{\bf A}f)$.

The answer is that it depends on ${\bf A}$.

If ${\bf A}= {\bf A_r}+{\bf A_{\theta,\phi}}$, i.e. is the sum of two operators, one acting on functions of $r$ only and not depending on $\theta$ and $\phi$, and the other acting on functions of $\theta,\phi$ and not depending on $r$, it is clear that
$$
{\bf A}f = \left( {\bf A_r}+{\bf A_{\theta,\phi}} \right)R(r)Y(\theta,\phi)= \left[ {\bf A_r}R(r) \right]Y(\theta,\phi) + R(r)\left[ {\bf A_{\theta,\phi}} Y(\theta,\phi)\right]
$$
and, if functions $R(r)$ and $Y(\theta,\phi)$ are normalized
$$
(f,{\bf A}f)=(R,{\bf A_r}R) + (Y,{\bf A_{\theta,\phi}}Y).
$$
It would be enough that one of the two operators would contain a function of the *other* coordinates to prevnt to obtain such result.

Of course, one can recast everything above in the formalism of *bra*, *kets* and tensor products between different Hilbert spaces. However I feel that  plain examples like this may be the best starting point for a more powerful formalism.

Answer (score 0):

If A is a one particle operator, such as kinetic energy or, effectively, the nuclear potential , then this reduces to

$$\langle \psi_1 \psi_2|\hat A|\psi_1 \psi_2\rangle = \langle \psi_1 |\hat A|\psi_1 \rangle + \langle \psi_2|\hat A| \psi_2\rangle$$

If A is a two particle operator such as the two electron interaction, then no reduction is possible.

Comment: This answer should probably warn about a common abuse of notation: the $\hat{A}$ on both sides of the equation are different operators. We're really talking about a two particle operator $\hat{A}_2 = \hat{A}\otimes \mathbb{1} + \mathbb{1} \otimes \hat{A}$.

Comment: No It is the same operator. It is the sum of two one particle operators. The unit operators are superfluous. If you are a quantum chemist solving a 1000 electron case you don't want to clutter your operators with a thousand unit operators.

Comment: But clearly OP is not a quantum chemist solving a 1000 electron case; they are a beginner, and these notation tricks should probably be pointed out.

Comment: So don't teach the OP cluttered, useless notation.one day he may be that quantum chemist.

Comment: As a beginner, I found the full notation of @Javier quite insightful and would have been upset if my teacher had intentionally tried to keep it a secret. Once you understand how a multi-particle operator works, you can of course simplify the notation to reduce clutter.

Comment: @noiraief If the operator is $$\Sigma_i p^2_i /2m$$ , the cluttered notation would make quite unreadable if not totally impracticable for a system with more than 2 particles. I don't see what a beginner would gain from that.

Comment: @my2cts they would gain the clarity of knowing that operators for different particles act on different Hilbert spaces, and thus they would avoid potential future mistakes by manipulating operators that don't talk to each other; e.g. false commutation relations, resulting to false charges etc.